# How to replace second column of csv file with a specific value "XYX"

Tags: sed, awk

To replace last field of csv file with `xyz` I use following command:

```
awk -F, '{$NF="xyz";}1' OFS=, file
```

How can I overwrite the second column of file with value `xyz`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `awk` the variable `NF` is the number of fields on the current line. You can refer to each field like `$1`,`$2`...`$NF` where `$1` is the first field and `$2` is the second field, upto `$NF` which is the last field on the current line *(i.e. if `NF` is 5 then `$NF` is `$5`).*

```
$ cat file
1,2,3,4,5

$ awk '$2="XYX"' FS=, OFS=, file
1,XYX,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for:

```
awk '{$2="XYX"}1' file
```

?

if you want `FS` to be comma:

```
 awk -F, '{$2="XYX"}1' OFS=, file
```