# How to use sed for substituting 2nd column in shell

Tags: sed

I have `file` that looks like this :

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

I want to substitute 2rd column containing 6 to 89. The desired output is

```
1,2,3,4
5,89,7,8
```

But if I type

```
index=2
cat file | sed 's/[^,]*/89/'$index
```

I get

```
1,89,3,4
5,89,7,8
```

and if I type

```
index=2
cat file | sed 's/[^,]6/89/'$index
```

nothing changes.
Why is it like this? How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: `[^,]` matches a single character which is not comma (or newline). It is unclear what you imagine it should match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace second column of csv file with a specific value "XYX"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745250/how-to-replace-second-column-of-csv-file-with-a-specific-value-xyx)

Comment: Also, the [`cat` is useless.](/q/11710552)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49833671/sed-replace-nth-column-of-multiple-tsv-files-without-header

Comment: Yes I did not know what [^,] means. Thank you! I don't need to substitute all lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to change the second column containing a `6` and you have a comma as field separator it is actually very easy with `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*\),6,/\1,89,/`
```

Here we make use of back-referencing to remember the first column.

If you want to replace the `6` in the 5th column, you can do something like:

```
sed 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{4\}\)6,/\189,/'
```

It is, however, much more comfortable using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}($2==6){$2=89}1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {if ($2==6) $2=89}1' file >file1
```